# How to attach files in 'page' in concrete5?

Tags: concrete5, concrete

I'm new to concrete5.

I need some pages with some different pdf files attached to them.

It seems in Composer - Page, the editor can only insert images.

I think 'add block content' is not proper, because the pdf files should just appear on certain pages.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look here - http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/viewing-pdf-file-on-the-website./ otherwise you can lookup the Impression plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert files (not just images). But if it's not working, try adding a "File" block to the page.